# finding appropriate place of a value from one column to another

Tags: excel-formula

I will be very grateful if someone can help me on the following task.

I have a column with date and hour and second column with values. I would like to create a new two colums, first one with date and hour but for 24 hour and second colum which to take from the values I already have for the same date and hour. Where there are no values to be return 0. For example for column2 and date2 2012-8-1 14:25 the value 6613 have to be taken from column 1 and data1 the time interval is 5 min

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question though it does not make a lot of sense without the details removed at an edit. A possible but rather cumbersome solution is to use some helper columns with index numbers for use with VLOOKUP. (There may be a much better way but if so you may have to wait a bit longer for it!)

Split the first column into two (date / time) with Data > Data Tools – Text to Columns, Fixed width.
Insert two columns (say C & D) between time and value and label the left one of these 172.

For 2012 8 1 14:25 in the left column put `=IF(C1=287,1,C1+1)` and in the right column `=A2&" "&C2`.
Create the 5 minute intervals with 2012 8 1 in say G1, and formulae in the next row as below:

G2 = `=G1+1/(24*12)`
H2 = `=IF(H1=287,1,H1+1)`
I2 = `=INT(G2+0.1)&" "&H2`
J2 = `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I2,D:E,2,FALSE),0)`

Copy down G2:J2 as required.
Hide any columns that are obtrusive.

It looks as though graphical presentation (a scatter chart) might be more suitable than tabular format.